# How do I enable the text view of the side admin bar

Tags: admin-bar

When I logged in today evening, I found that all the text in the admin bar had disappeared and only the icons were visible as shown below

[image]

How do I enable the text again

Comment: Click on [this button](http://prntscr.com/619304) at the very below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very bottom there should be an icon that looks like a play button:

[image: Icon to toggle menu with]

Click it! ;)

Comment: Ok that is embarrassing that I asked such a silly question, I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer as soon as 10 minutes have gone by :)